# Showing a Rails Post's pageviews in Morris.js chart

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, morris.js

*I apologize for the vague title*

Using rails, I am trying to show, in a chart, the relationship between the Post name and the number of pageviews that Post has. To accomplish this, I'm using the impressionist gem (https://github.com/charlotte-ruby/impressionist), which is working great and Morris.js (http://www.oesmith.co.uk/morris.js/) for charts and graphs.

I'm trying to show the graph on the Post's index page

```
def index
  @posts = Post.all
end
```

In order to find the number of page views on a Post, you use

```
<%= @post.impressionist_count =%>
```

Unfortunately, I'm having trouble implementing this with the Morris.js.

Here is the morris js i'm using, and i've tried many things in the 'ykeys', but can't get it to work. Maybe i can better accomplish this by using a helper method? I am relatively new to ruby (2 months) and it always seem like my questions get answered here.

```
new Morris.Line({
  element: 'post_graph',
    data: $("#post_graph").data('posts'),
    xkey: 'created_at',
    ykeys: [<%= @post.impressionist_count %>],
    labels: ['Page Views']
  });
```

And posts/index.html.erb

```
<%= content_tag :div, "", id: "post_graph", data: {posts: @posts} %>
```

Thanks in advance to all who help out

Answer (score 0):

Never touched Morris nor Impressionist, but but I think you need to do:

```
<%= content_tag :div, "", id: "post_graph", data: {posts: @post.impressionist_count.to_json} %>
```

and:

```
new Morris.Line({
  element: 'post_graph',
  data: $("#post_graph").data('posts'),
  xkey: 'created_at',
  ykeys: ['impressions'],
  labels: ['Page Views']
});
```

Although I would perhaps not put the JSON in the DOM and change both to:

```
<%= content_tag :div, "", id: "post_graph" %>
```

and this JS in the same view file:

```
new Morris.Line({
  element: 'post_graph',
  data: <%= @post.impressionist_count.to_json %>,
  xkey: 'created_at',
  ykeys: ['impressions'],
  labels: ['Page Views']
});
```

Not sure if `ykeys` should be named `impressions`, change that to the relevant fieldname.